# in ember, how do I unit test controller action that sends another action?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-qunit

I have following controller

```
MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({ 
  actions: {
    doSomething: function(param1, param2) {
      this.send('actionName', param1, param2);
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a way to write an unit test that verifies that this controller will bubble up this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `target` of your subject (controller) and let your `target` have `actionName` declared in `actions` object:

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('controller:my-controller');

test('it fires an action', function(assert) {
  let controller = this.subject();

  controller.set('target', Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        actionName: () => assert.ok(true, 'Action bubbled!')
    }
  }).create());

  controller.send('doSomething');
});
```

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/0938e8f8fcee8ebbd5f94dfa81e3f2cc?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=tests.unit.controllers.my-controller-test.js%2C)